# Set a subtitle language using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I tried googling a way to set the language of a subtitle stream with ffmpeg and found the -slang option. So I tried the following command but immediately receive an error:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i subs.srt -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -slang eng -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 output.mp4
ffmpeg version 1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jul 18 2013 23:00:53 with Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
```

> libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
>
> libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
>
> libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
>
> libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
>
> libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
>
> libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
>
> libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
>
> libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
>
> Unrecognized option 'slang'.
>
> Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

After more googling I found another way to do it using the -metadata command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i subs.srt -c:a copy -c:v copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng output.mp4
```

And that works absolutely fine. But this isn't mentioned in the ffmpeg man page, whereas -slang is, which makes me think the -metadata command is maybe outdated or in some other way not as good as -slang.

1. What is the difference between using the two above methods (-slang vs -metadata)?
2. Why did my -slang command give an error? Have I used it incorrectly?

Comment: You should include the compete ffmpeg console output for each of your ffmpeg commands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research, found the reason why -slang didn't work. In fact you use a recent version of ffmpeg and it's a good thing but if [the documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Subtitle-options_003a) still describe the option, you can find in the [ChangeLog](https://raw.github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/Changelog):

```
version 0.9:
...
 * -metadata can now be used to set metadata on streams and chapters, e.g.
      -metadata:s:1 language=eng sets the language of the first stream to 'eng'.
      This made -vlang/-alang/-slang options redundant, so they were removed.
```

When you find a command line example, check if the option used are in Your version of ffmpeg.

```
 ffmpeg --help >> ffmpeg-doc.txt
```

The `-slang` option isn't in.

But it also proof that the on-line documentation about ffmpeg is sometime incorrect regarding the code change.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Any idea why this metadata command seems to index the streams from 1 whereas when mapping streams and performing other actions, streams are indexed from zero? I would have thought `-metadata:s:1 language=eng` would set the second stream to english and to set the first stream you would use `-metadata:s:0 language=eng`. Any thoughts?

Comment: This indexing *is* consistent with the rest of the indexing.  Everything starts at 0 (programmers, sigh...).  In this case, stream 0 is the video stream (this is always the case with MP4?).  So, you specify the first audio as either `-metadata:s:1` (the 2nd stream in the file) or more correctly as `-metadata:s:a:0` (the first *audio* stream in the file).

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about which naming convention to use for the language (in my case, trying to specify Finnish). Going from the `eng` example, I'd assume [ISO 639-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) (eg. `fin` for Finnish)?

Answer (score 38):

The option

> -metadata:s:1 language=eng

sets metadata language to `eng` on the stream id 1 (which is, in typical cases, the first audio stream). Whereas the option

> -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng

sets the metadata language to `eng` on the first subtitle stream.

From ffmpeg manpage:

> -metadata[:metadata_specifier] key=value (output,per-metadata)
>   Set a metadata key/value pair.
>
> An optional `metadata_specifier` may be given to set metadata on streams or chapters. See "-map_metadata" documentation for details.
>
> s[:stream_spec]
>   per-stream metadata. `stream_spec` is a stream specifier as described in the Stream specifiers chapter. In an input metadata specifier, the first matching stream is copied from. In an output metadata specifier, all matching streams are copied to.

And finally from the chapter of stream specifiers, we see

> Possible forms of stream specifiers are:
>   `stream_index`
>   Matches the stream with this index. E.g. "-threads:1 4" would set the thread count for the second stream to 4.
>
> `stream_type[:stream_index]`
>   `stream_type` is one of: 'v' for video, 'a' for audio, 's' for subtitle, 'd' for data and 't' for attachments. If `stream_index` is given, then matches stream number `stream_index` of this type. Otherwise matches all streams of this type.